# Is it possible to find the bounds of a function from a differential inequality?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I have a differential inequality of the form

$u'(t) \leq \frac{u(t)}{t} = \frac{1}{t}.u(t)= \beta(t).u(t)$ , where $\beta(t) = \frac{1}{t}$

and

$t \in [-1.0, +1.0]$ and $u(t) > 0 \forall t$

Looking at the differential form of Gronwall's Inequality, I figured that it will not be possible to apply it, as $\beta(t)$ is non-differentiable in $[-1.0, +1.0]$

The main question is, can we find the bounds of the function $u(t)$, from the above differential equation for the given conditions? If yes, then how should one proceed?

If we consider two separate half-planes (positive and negative), will it be possible to find the bounds separately for the two half-planes?

Comment: Is $u(t)$ just any function? Because, as it stands, there is no bound.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza... Yes $u(t)$ can be any function such that $u(t) > 0 \forall t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u(t)$ is a function that solves the inequality. Define $g(t) = M\, u(t)$ for any fixed $M > 0$ and observe that,

$$g'(t) = M\, u'(t) \leq M\, \beta(t)\, u(t) = \beta(t)\, g(t).$$

This shows that if the space of solutions is non-empty, then a bound cannot be found since one can always find a solution that takes on a larger value in the domain. Note, the specific choice of $\beta(t)$ is not relevant. As a result, more conditions are required to ensure the space of solutions is bounded.